# how do I unblock the app blocked with adb shell pm block command?

Tags: android, windows, adb, sony-xperia

I need to enable an app that I blocked using `adb` because my phone is force closing now. How do I reenable the app? I used the

```
adb shell pm block com.sonymobile.advancedwidget.entrance
```

command to block it.

Comment: obviously `pm unblock com.sonymobile.advancedwidget.entrance`

Comment: Might be obvious, but difficult to find documentation on. In the end, better be careful with adb commands than just try something without knowing what will happen.

Comment: @WouterVanVliet,when we type "adb shell pm" in the shell,it will list the usage of pm command.And below "pm block PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT" is "pm unblock PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `pm unblock` command:

```
adb shell pm unblock com.sonymobile.advancedwidget.entrance
```